# How do you set the selected item in a qnx.fuse.ui.listClasses.SectionList?

Tags: air, blackberry-playbook

So, when the user clicks on the SectionList, it's easy to get the ICellRenderer selected and change it's state to selected:

```
this.messagesList.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICKED, messageSelected);    

//Skip some lines...

private function messageSelected(event:ListEvent):void {
    event.cell.state = SkinStates.SELECTED;
}
```

In my application, I'm saving the child index and the section index of the currently selected item in the list.  The problem is that I have no way of accesing the ICellRenderer at that location.  Using

```
this.messagesList.selectedItem = selectedMessage;
```

doesn't work, either.

Any suggestions?   Ideally I would like a function something like

```
this.messagesList.getCellRendererAt(section:int, child:int)
```

but I can't find any such methods in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm a dummy.

```
this.messagesList.selectedItem = foo;
```

works just fine.  Turns out I was doing some other stupid stuff in my code that later cleared the selected item.